# Find Next Date/Day in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables for which I need to find a date. In other words, I am trying to solve two problems which I feel are closely related.

Table 1: Has today's date in a column. From this date I need to populate another column with the date of the next Friday. In other words, if today is 10/6/19, I want the new column to populate with 10/11/19.

Table 2: Has the day number of "1" in a column. From this number, I need to populate another column with next month's date using that day number. In other words, if today is 10/6/19, I want the new column to populate with 11/1/19.

Any help would be much appreciated. I know how to do this in Excel, but after reviewing a bunch of posts and a list of M date functions, I'm at a loss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. Perhaps the following will help.

If you have a column of dates, to add a column which will show the "next Friday", the Custom Column formula:

```
=Date.AddDays([dates],7-Date.DayOfWeek([dates],5))
```

Your second question, if you have a column of numbers (eg Index), a formula which will return the date `n` months in the future on the same date as `today`:

```
=Date.AddMonths(DateTime.LocalNow(),[Index])
```

*Consider using `.FixedLocalNow` after reading about the difference*

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!